# Hyperlinks are not opened in new tab

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I have seen when some OP post reference links to their questions, it always go to that page in the current tab which I opened at that moment. That is really annoying when I have to back and forth.

[Test here](https://www.google.lk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=3PqHVse2M8f08weYiYjYBQ&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Has been previously requested on network meta and declined. You can easily open links in new tabs by using the mousewheel or Ctrl

Comment: This is not specific to Code Review and should be asked on the main Meta instead of here. It's off-topic for this meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been requested several times, all over the place, and rejected pretty universally. A few examples:

- [Make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window) (Meta.SE)
- [Why doesn't Stack Exchange open links in a new tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237745/why-doesnt-stack-exchange-open-links-in-a-new-tab)
- [Why aren't hyperlinks opened in a new window?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252367/why-arent-hyperlinks-opened-in-a-new-window) (Meta.SO)
- [Open links in new tab](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10736/open-links-in-new-tab) (Meta.Math)
- [Make external links open in new window/tab](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/make-external-links-open-in-new-window-tab) (Meta.WordPress)
- [Why does clicking on a link not open a new tab?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/why-does-clicking-on-a-link-not-open-a-new-tab) (Meta.English)

You can find a bunch more pretty easily with something like this in Google Search:

```
link new tab site:meta.*.stackexchange.com
```

The only positively voted one I found easily was on TeX.SE's meta, and even there, the first comment disagrees and has many more upvotes than the question.

In short: this won't happen. As for why, you can get some insightful UX research concerning this topic on UX.SE (in addition to the various replies on the meta posts above), for example:

- [Opening website external links in new window — published usability tests](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19892/opening-website-external-links-in-new-window-published-usability-tests)
- [Is there ever a good reason to force opening a new browser window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13727/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-force-opening-a-new-browser-window?lq=1)

And a few more - check out the "linked" and "related" links on those pages.